# Issue inserting timestamp in Postgres table

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to insert a value in the postgres table through Java . Column type is timestamp.

The code is like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
String gameStartedTime = format.format(new Date());

String query= "UPDATE gameStatus g SET g.status ='" + gameStatus
    + g.gameStartTime= to_date('"
            + gameStartedTime  + "','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')"
    // Doesn't matter much
+ " WHERE g.status = 'STARTED' AND " + "g.condition="+ game.getCondition();
```

Now when I try to execute this statement it fails I get the message like this :

> ERROR:  conflicting values for "mm" field in formatting string.
>   DETAIL:  This value contradicts a previous setting for the same field type.

I am not sure what is going wrong !!

Any help on this will be useful.
Thanks in advance.
-JE

Comment: Use java.sql.Date and convert Date to time Stamp like this
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(sign_date.getTime());
  this.sign_date = timestamp;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mm` is **always** the month for the `to_date()` function. There is no difference between `mm` and `MM` (unlike in Java's SimpleDateFormat).

You need to use `mi` for the minutes.

A full list of all patterns is available in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

But you shouldn't use "dynamic" SQL in the first place. It's better to use a `PreparedStatement`, `java.sql.Timestamp` and `setTimestamp()` instead. That relief you from any formatting problems and protect you against SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

do like this.

```
java.sql.Date date=new Date();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
this.date = timestamp;
```

Then add `this.date` into database..

Answer (score 2):

**try it:**
ps.setTimestamp(position, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));

Answer (score 1):

Try to split the date part from the query and try to compare these values.
It appears (at least from where I see) that the mm which stand for minutes, 
does not comply with `g.gameStartTime= to_date`.

If you pull this part outside the query you can check the values, maybe you will find what the problem is there.

Comment: `mm` does **not** stand for *Minutes*

Comment: Whoops, thanks a_horse_with_no_name. So I learned somnething myself also.

Answer (score 1):

This way works for me using current time:

```
    String query = "INSERT INTO table1 (id,t) VALUES (?, ?)"; 
    //update table1 set t=? where id=?
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

        ps.setLong(1, 1234); // update ps.setLong(2, 1234);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
        ps.setTimestamp(2,timestamp); // ps.setTimestamp(1,timestamp);
        int out = ps.executeUpdate();
        if(out !=0){
            System.out.println("Record saved");
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Or, you can establish a specific timestamp by using these lines:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0); // 0 january
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 26); 
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10); 
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 47);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```